# Bash: Move specific line of content in file to the top of the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm making a script (in vim) that goes through a file and looks for a specific line. If the line matches, I want it to be moved to the top of the file.

The file looks something like this:

```
6596628c9cbab49b80d6a07d0304377768f5114e7f8b21edffa820aab1c508be, ./favicon.ico
150a04dd76f733e5ef05ece49de115d05f71efa8e73025e015dd4e0fb3217553, ./about.php
28acfc4b0d378c22a2c0e4913cae3d15aef9b21938de81be92f74aef85b0cc0e, ./info.php
67976bbbd1b62a00d454da3a9f95e72d97d0fd156d4c65a12707f2602cbea582, ./missing.php
6ed318718f4cc617c82121db7cde54188eac6f89c355f0bfe9d198218de7fffc, ./browse.php
abd277cc3453be980bb48cbffe9d1f7422ca1ef4bc0b7d035fda87cea4d55cbc, ./composer.phar
73ac79eccac12120dc601cd6cce1282a1d8a920d440d3d1141d257db1ed4b0f0, ./search.php
f412aabd74f4c99bd32c5e534132c565f52c2bd32fbf7f629eb5a4495ac46351, ./index.php
c2d49a4873088fbe635d8653494f7f1425b6ad9f55d63ee4de52170d8a8d01b8, ./content/style.css
18e7d61367d80bc125b309ac002bb3946c5e7ba419ef59537afc939eff799dfd, ./content/logo.png
d8da15f62d55641320f7e7c21d9be86db6d81f7667bbd35c738b4c917cad3ce9, ./robots.txt
```

How would I be able to move the content on line 8 (index.php) to the top so it looks like this:

```
f412aabd74f4c99bd32c5e534132c565f52c2bd32fbf7f629eb5a4495ac46351, ./index.php
6596628c9cbab49b80d6a07d0304377768f5114e7f8b21edffa820aab1c508be, ./favicon.ico
150a04dd76f733e5ef05ece49de115d05f71efa8e73025e015dd4e0fb3217553, ./about.php
28acfc4b0d378c22a2c0e4913cae3d15aef9b21938de81be92f74aef85b0cc0e, ./info.php
67976bbbd1b62a00d454da3a9f95e72d97d0fd156d4c65a12707f2602cbea582, ./missing.php
6ed318718f4cc617c82121db7cde54188eac6f89c355f0bfe9d198218de7fffc, ./browse.php
abd277cc3453be980bb48cbffe9d1f7422ca1ef4bc0b7d035fda87cea4d55cbc, ./composer.phar
73ac79eccac12120dc601cd6cce1282a1d8a920d440d3d1141d257db1ed4b0f0, ./search.php
c2d49a4873088fbe635d8653494f7f1425b6ad9f55d63ee4de52170d8a8d01b8, ./content/style.css
18e7d61367d80bc125b309ac002bb3946c5e7ba419ef59537afc939eff799dfd, ./content/logo.png
d8da15f62d55641320f7e7c21d9be86db6d81f7667bbd35c738b4c917cad3ce9, ./robots.txt
```

*(The file contains about 9000 lines)*

How can this be done most efficiently?

Comment: If you are using vim, why not `:8m0` ? If line number isn't fixed, use `:/index\.php/m0`

Comment: @Sundeep Well not exactly, and this is why it was so hard to google the spesifics for doing this in vim. So I wanted to do a `call system("bash command")` instead. This is the function I'm writing: https://i.imgur.com/YnvLBSM.png

Comment: Why would you write a script in `vim`? Either what you're doing is a simple one-off in which case you'd use a graphical editor like vim, or it's non-trivial and/or frequently repeated and then you'd use a command-line editing tool like awk or sed or even ed.

Comment: Do you want to move line 8 no matter what it contains or do you want to move the line that contains "index.php" no matter which line number it's on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think can use `sed` to do the operations needed:
This command will be used to get the content in the file at specific line

```
sed -n "$LINE_NUMBER"p "$FILENAME"
```

This command will be used to delete the content of the file at specified line

```
sed -i.bak -e "$LINE_NUMBER"'d' "$FILENAME"
```

And finally, this command will be used to append a string to the top of a file

```
sed -i -e "1i${LINE_CONTENT}" "$FILENAME"
```

Combine the 3 commands together, you can perform the operation mentioned in your question (test.log is the file that contain your sample input)

```
FILENAME="test.log"
LINE_NUMBER=8
LINE_CONTENT=$(sed -n "$LINE_NUMBER"p "$FILENAME")
sed -i.bak -e "$LINE_NUMBER"'d' "$FILENAME"
sed -i -e "1i${LINE_CONTENT}" "$FILENAME"
```

Answer (score 3):

With `ed`, this will do in-place editing as well:

```sh
printf '8m0\nwq\n' | ed -s ip.txt -
```

Or, if you don't know line number:

```sh
printf '/index\.php/m0\nwq\n' | ed -s ip.txt -
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your file name is `test.txt`, you can try this:
(Please backup your file first)

```
grep "./index.php" test.txt > out && grep -v "./index.php" test.txt >> out && mv out test.txt
```

Comment: Is it not possible to specify the line number? Do I have to use grep here?

Comment: @Typewar you can also try using ``sed``.

Comment: For some reason it sets a number in front of the string `8:f4cd261a896fe4e7295146e7eb8ec39220e3aff1945e2e7ea57969199d5fab02, ./index.php`

Comment: @Typewar I edited the answer so the number does not appear. That number was the row number.

Comment: I don't think this is efficient since you need to filter the same file twice and then concatenate the results, but it's very creative. I like the solution

Comment: @Bri4n it's probably more efficient than [the currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67031220/1745001) that uses 3 calls to sed and 2 backup files!

Answer (score 1):

To do this job reading the input file just once without reading  the whole file into memory, and using any awk in any shell on every Unix box all you need is either of these:

```
awk 'f{print; next} NR==8{print $0 buf; f=1} {buf=buf ORS $0}' file

awk 'f{print; next} $2=="./index.php"{print $0 buf; f=1} {buf=buf ORS $0}' file
```

If you want to move the 8th line to the top:

```
$ awk 'f{print; next} NR==8{print $0 buf; f=1} {buf=buf ORS $0}' file
f412aabd74f4c99bd32c5e534132c565f52c2bd32fbf7f629eb5a4495ac46351, ./index.php
6596628c9cbab49b80d6a07d0304377768f5114e7f8b21edffa820aab1c508be, ./favicon.ico
150a04dd76f733e5ef05ece49de115d05f71efa8e73025e015dd4e0fb3217553, ./about.php
28acfc4b0d378c22a2c0e4913cae3d15aef9b21938de81be92f74aef85b0cc0e, ./info.php
67976bbbd1b62a00d454da3a9f95e72d97d0fd156d4c65a12707f2602cbea582, ./missing.php
6ed318718f4cc617c82121db7cde54188eac6f89c355f0bfe9d198218de7fffc, ./browse.php
abd277cc3453be980bb48cbffe9d1f7422ca1ef4bc0b7d035fda87cea4d55cbc, ./composer.phar
73ac79eccac12120dc601cd6cce1282a1d8a920d440d3d1141d257db1ed4b0f0, ./search.php
c2d49a4873088fbe635d8653494f7f1425b6ad9f55d63ee4de52170d8a8d01b8, ./content/style.css
18e7d61367d80bc125b309ac002bb3946c5e7ba419ef59537afc939eff799dfd, ./content/logo.png
d8da15f62d55641320f7e7c21d9be86db6d81f7667bbd35c738b4c917cad3ce9, ./robots.txt
```

If you want to move the line containing "index" to the top:

```
$ awk 'f{print; next} $2=="./index.php"{print $0 buf; f=1} {buf=buf ORS $0}' file
f412aabd74f4c99bd32c5e534132c565f52c2bd32fbf7f629eb5a4495ac46351, ./index.php
6596628c9cbab49b80d6a07d0304377768f5114e7f8b21edffa820aab1c508be, ./favicon.ico
150a04dd76f733e5ef05ece49de115d05f71efa8e73025e015dd4e0fb3217553, ./about.php
28acfc4b0d378c22a2c0e4913cae3d15aef9b21938de81be92f74aef85b0cc0e, ./info.php
67976bbbd1b62a00d454da3a9f95e72d97d0fd156d4c65a12707f2602cbea582, ./missing.php
6ed318718f4cc617c82121db7cde54188eac6f89c355f0bfe9d198218de7fffc, ./browse.php
abd277cc3453be980bb48cbffe9d1f7422ca1ef4bc0b7d035fda87cea4d55cbc, ./composer.phar
73ac79eccac12120dc601cd6cce1282a1d8a920d440d3d1141d257db1ed4b0f0, ./search.php
c2d49a4873088fbe635d8653494f7f1425b6ad9f55d63ee4de52170d8a8d01b8, ./content/style.css
18e7d61367d80bc125b309ac002bb3946c5e7ba419ef59537afc939eff799dfd, ./content/logo.png
d8da15f62d55641320f7e7c21d9be86db6d81f7667bbd35c738b4c917cad3ce9, ./robots.txt
```

To modify the original file if you have GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace '...script...' file
```

or with any awk:

```
awk '...script...' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: This is the best answer !! simple and beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1,8{H;8!d;p;x;s/^(.)(.*)\1.*/\2/}' file
```

Create a range of lines in the hold space from the first to the line number to be inserted at the start of the file (in the example above line 8).

When the current line is the desired line, print it and then swap to the hold space, remove the newline introduced at the start of the range and the last line added (the desired line) and print the remainder too.

All other lines will be printed as normal.

Alternative:

```
sed -E '1{:a;N;8!ba;s/(.*)(\n)(.*)/\3\2\1/}' file
```

Yet another quirky solution:

```
sed '1,7{H;d};8{p;x;D}' file
```